# [Mininet/MiniEdit]: Routing doesn't seem to work in case of 2 routers

Tags: networking, routing

As a part of an experiment in [Mininet](http://mininet.org/),
my IPv4 network has the following topology for two host machines
connected via two routers. 
(Running Mininet on an Ubuntu 22.04.02 Virtual Machine.)

```
  N.0.103              N.0.1  N.2.1                N.2.2  N.1.1                N.1.2
h1 ------------------------ r1 ------------------------ r2 ------------------------ h2
           N.0.0/24                    N.2.0/24                    N.1.0/24
```

The top row is interface addresses and the bottom row is network addresses,
where `N` = 192.168.

In detail,
the host Machine 'h1' has the following configuration:

```
h1-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::70e9:dfff:fe2c:6242  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:e9:df:2c:62:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The host Machine 'h2' has the following config:

```
h2-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f429:9fff:fe6a:5211  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:29:9f:6a:52:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The router 'r1' has the following config:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r1-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::10dc:6cff:feb2:1688  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:dc:6c:b2:16:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r1-eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::8cd5:99ff:fedf:e2a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8e:d5:99:df:e2:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The router 'r2' has the following configuration:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r2-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::87d:6aff:fee9:477  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:7d:6a:e9:04:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21  bytes 1398 (1.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r2-eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::cc40:70ff:fe31:f96d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:40:70:31:f9:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am trying to set up the experimental topology
such that both the hosts can access the other,
which, of course, is possible through configuring routing tables.

I have taken the following steps:

On the **r1 terminal (xterm):**

```bash
    ifconfig r1-eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ifconfig r1-eth1 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev r1-eth0   
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.2
```

On the **r2 terminal (xterm):**

```bash
    ifconfig r2-eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig r2-eth1 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.1   
    ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev r1-eth1
```

On the **h1 terminal (xterm)**

```bash
    ifconfig h1-eth0 192.168.0.103 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add default gw 192.168.0.1
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

On the **h2 terminal (xterm)**

```bash
    ifconfig h2-eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add default gw 192.168.1.1
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

The updated routing tables for h1, h2, r1 and r2 are as follows:

**h1 Routes**:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 h1-eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 h1-eth0
192.168.1.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 h1-eth0
```

**h2 routes**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 h2-eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 h2-eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 h2-eth0
```

**r1 route tables**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r1-eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r1-eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r1-eth1
```

**r2 route tables** :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r2-eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r2-eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r2-eth1
```

When I try pinging 'h2' from 'h1' and vice versa,
I get a "Destination host unreachable" error.

Here is my ping reachability matrix
(as generated by `pingall` on the Mininet CLI) to show some results:

```
 r1 -> r2 h1 X 
 r2 -> r1 X X 
 h1 -> r1 r2 X 
 h2 -> r1 r2 X
```

It can be interpreted as :

Through pinging,

1. `r1` can reach `r2` and `h1` but not `h2`.
2. `r2` can reach `r1`          but can't reach `h1` nor `h2`.
3. `h1` can reach `r1` and `r2` but not `h2`.
4. `h2` can reach `r1` and `r2` but not `h1`.

As an actual matrix,

| The below node can ping which other nodes | r1 | r2 | h1 | h2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **r1** | - | Yes | Yes |  |
| **r2** | Yes | - |  |  |
| **h1** | Yes | Yes | - |  |
| **h2** | Yes | Yes |  | - |

Where am I going wrong? 
Is there a step I have skipped? 
Any insight/help is appreciated.

Comment: When you edit your question, don't write "Edit" and explain the error. Instead, fix the error so that the question is corrected. Make it easy for people to read what's going on without them needing to read all the answers and comments

Comment: I have merged the accounts and implemented the changes you and @Hauke suggested. But still, I get the same ping reachability matrix as put in the updates. Also, notes taken. I will remember that rule in the future.

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Comment: Hi @roaima. How do I do that? It says `You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits`

Comment: What does your "ping reachability matrix" show us?

Comment: So when you press `pingall` on the mininet CLI, it shows you the ping reachability matrix and can be interpreted as follows:

Taking as an example

`r1 -> r2  h1 X`

It means `r1` via pinging can reach `r2` and `h1`, but can't reach `h2`

Comment: Please add the explanation into your question. The more that gets added into comments the harder it is for people to grasp the whole issue

Comment: Added the explanation via an edit. Please please have a look.

Comment: (0) Please check my edits and verify that I didn’t make any mistakes. (1) If you have solved your problem, or no longer need our help, please tell us so.  If a posted answer helps you solve your problem, “accept” that answer. (2) ``h2`` can ping ``r2``, so the “physical connectivity” between them works.  But ``r2`` can’t ping ``h2``, even though they’re “directly connected”.  Can ``h2`` ping itself?  Try to solve that problem and update us.

Comment: This question describes a setup that has a fundamental flaw — nodes ``r2`` and ``h2``, which are “physically connected”, cannot ping each other.  (`h2` can ping `r2`, but `r2` can’t ping `h2`.)  Nobody can see anything in the question that would explain this, and the OP has not responded to my request that they troubleshoot that localized problem and provide more information.  So it seems unlikely that anybody will be able to answer this question as it stands now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo:

```
# On the h1 terminal (xterm)
[...]
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

What I guess you intended to type (consistent with h2) is

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

This error is especially sad because these entries are completely useless. In both cases the default route would have covered it.

In general: With such problems you should run `tcpdump` on all hosts in order to see how far the packet goes.

And you can test the local routing configuration with

```
ip route get 1.2.3.4 # tells you what would happen with a packet to that address
```

## Update 1

The routing tables on the routers seem to be wrong. Took me some time to notice because I am not used to the output of `route`. You should use `ip address` and `ip link` instead of `ifconfig` and `ip route` instead of `route`.

The routing tables of the routers must contain two link entries (for the two interfaces) and one nexthop entry. But all the entries look the same.

The reason is a missing route configuration on each router. Each one needs (different) entries for

- 192.168.0.0/24
- 192.168.0.1/24
- 192.168.0.2/24

`r1` is missing:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev r1-eth1
```

`r2` is missing:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev r2-eth0
```

Comment: @roaima I was surprised, too. You just don't expect to notice such tiny problems when confronted with such a flood of config data.

Comment: Hi @Hauke. I tried using your commands, but I got a 
`RTNETLINK answers: File exists` every single time.
Also for the r2 missing part, shouldn't it be r2-eth0?

Comment: @tahuja2 You are right, must be `r2-eth0`. I corrected that. Please add the output of `ip route` on `r1` and `r2` to your question. What about `tcdump`?

Comment: so I ran the following tcpdump commands on both the hosts and all I get on the terminal is:

`0 packets captured`

`0 packets received by the filter`

`0 packets dropped by the kernel`

Comment: You should run tcpdump on the next host. So if you run `ping` on `h1` then you should start with `tcpdump` on `r1`, connected to `eth0`. If you see the packet there, then check by connecting to `eth1` whether it passes through the host. If so then run it on `r2`.

Comment: So I ran `tcpdump` on `r1` and pinged via `h1` and I saw the packets. So now do you want me to run `tcpdump` on `r2` and run `ping` on `r1`? I am sorry is that what you are trying to convey?

Comment: You need to follow the chain, @tahuja2, to see where they're getting lost. Remember to check both interfaces on each router r1, r2

Comment: Also in my edits I have mentioned the ping reachability matrix. Does it help by any chance?

Comment: @tahuja2 `ping` and `tcpdump` may give different results. `ping` just shows you whether the packets make all the way to the target and the responses make it all the way back. It is enough to run `ping` on `h1` and `h2` but we must know where the problem is. Does the `echo request` from `h1` reach `h2` or not? Does `h2` send an `echo reply`? Which of those two packets gets lost and between which two hosts? I would still like to see the output of `ip route` on the routers.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably not enabled forwarding on r1 and r2

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Before you run this (or after) you can check the current state

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

0 indicates it's not been enabled, 1 otherwise